# How to create a typeclass instance for any subclass of Traversable in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I've created a toy example to illustrate a compiler error that I don't understand. Shouldn't the implicit conversion from `C[_] <: Traversable[T]` with `Safe[T]` to `Safe[C[T]]` apply?

```
import scala.language.{implicitConversions, higherKinds}

class ToyExample {

  implicit val stringsafe = new Safe[String] {
    override def stringify(value: String): String = value
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a: String = "c"
    val b: Seq[String] = Seq("1", "2", "3")
    safe(a)
    safe(b)  // why is this a compiler error?
  }

  def safe[T](value: T)(implicit safe: Safe[T]): String = safe stringify value
}

object Safe {

  implicit def safeTraversable[C[_] <: Traversable[T], T](implicit safe: Safe[T]): Safe[C[T]] =
    new Safe[C[T]] {
      override def stringify(value: C[T]): String = value.map(safe.stringify).toString()
    }
}

trait Safe[T] {

  def stringify(value: T): String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out how to get the code to compile, but I don't understand the reason.

By modifying the implicit conversion to remove the higher-kinded placeholder, I was able to get it to compile:

```
implicit def safeTraversable[C <: Traversable[T], T](implicit safe: Safe[T]): Safe[C] =
    new Safe[C] {
      override def stringify(value: C): String = value.map(safe.stringify).toString()
    }
```

Does anyone understand why the higher kinded type would be invalid?

Comment: See "Common Pitfalls" at  http://adriaanm.github.io/research/2010/10/06/new-in-scala-2.8-type-constructor-inference/, where [Adriaan Moors](http://stackoverflow.com/users/276895/adriaan-moors) writes, "perhaps surprisingly, `CC[_] <: Traversable[_]` is not equivalent to `CC[X] <: Traversable[X]`..."

Comment: Here's my own attempt at a short explanation. `C[_] <: Traversable[T]` means `C[X] <: Traversable[T]`, for some fresh name X, but that doesn't constrain `X` and `T` to have anything whatsoever to do with each other. If that seems puzzling, consider: I can write `class Foo[T] extends Traversable[Int]`, but `T` can still be anything; it is not constrained to be a subtype of `Int`. After all, `Foo` isn't required to have a type parameter at all; `class Foo extends Traversable[Int]` is a perfectly sensible thing to write.